# Modern CMake/c++ and vcpkg project setup for large projects

Tags: c++, cmake

I am starting up a project with some people, because there will be developed for and on multiple platforms  we chose to use CMake to build our project. Because the project will get quite large we are trying to have a good setup but we lack the experience needed in CMake to make well thought out decisions.

We are using vcpkg for installing and using package as described as best practice to use it as submodule in combination with cmake.

We are mostly looking for the following answers.

- Does the directory structure hold up when the project gets larger.
- Should all header files be in the includes directory or only the public ones.
- Does this project use the proper modern CMake conventions.
- Is vcpkg a the right choice for these kind of projects(multi-platform)
- for now we have 2 libraries(Cheetah.Engine and Cheetah.Editor) we suspect it will be a lot more, could it be smart to seperate these libraries to their own projects?

**Our directory structure**:
[image: image of directory srtucture]

**Root CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# CMakeList.txt : Top-level CMake project file, do global configuration
# and include sub-projects here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.18)

project ("Cheetah")

# Platform defines for all projects
IF (WIN32)
  add_compile_definitions(CH_PLATFORM_WINDOWS)
ELSE()
  # set stuff for other systems
ENDIF()

# Set ouput projects so no need to copy dll's after build
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

# Include sub-projects.
add_subdirectory ("Cheetah.Engine")
add_subdirectory ("Cheetah.Editor")
add_subdirectory ("Sandbox")
```

**Subdirectory CMakeLists.txt of Cheetah.Engine**:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.18)

add_library (Cheetah.Engine SHARED "")

# add sources
add_subdirectory("src")
add_subdirectory("includes")


# add includes
target_include_directories(Cheetah.Engine PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/includes")

# add macros
target_compile_definitions(Cheetah.Engine PRIVATE "CH_BUILD_DLL")

# add libraries
find_package(glad CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(Cheetah.Engine PRIVATE glad::glad)

find_package(glfw3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(Cheetah.Engine PRIVATE glfw3)
```

**Example of includes folder CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.18)

target_sources(Cheetah.Engine 
    INTERFACE 
        "Application.h"
        "EntryPoint.h"
     PRIVATE 
        "Core.h"
     )
```

We are still debating if the core.h should be with the source files outside of the includes folder because it is a private header file.

**Example of source folder CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.18)

target_sources(Cheetah.Engine PRIVATE "Application.cpp")
```